# How can I prevent OneNote 2013 from constantly respawning the "Quick Notes" section?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I'm trying to use OneNote 2013 to start organizing everything in my job.  Every time I delete the "Quick Notes" section, it immediately is recreated.  I want it gone forever.  Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

[image: quick notes tab]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One solution I found is running a script that deletes the `Quick Notes.one` file in `%userprofile%\Documents\OneNote Notebooks\My Notebook` periodically. It doesn't appear that there is an option to disable it being recreated.

Another option comes from [one of the replies in this thread on the Microsoft forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/unable-to-delete-section-quick-notes-in/fbc06e27-489e-4a1d-861b-0b1c63d21f9a):

> I had to look back at how I did this on my OneNote. Open OneNote. Go
>   to File, then select Options. Choose Save & Backup on the left of the
>   window that opens. At the top of this window there should be a Save
>   section and you will see Quick Notes Section, Backup Folder and
>   Default Notebook Location and the location.
>
> Change Quick Notes Section to another existing section in your
>   OneNote. I made Quick Notes section refer to my Daily notes section
>   that I type daily notes into and a Quick Notes section tab never
>   appears on it's own anymore. Hope this helps.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The changing of the Quick Notes Section worked.  (Kind of sucks that I think I'm now syncing some random section, but hey.)

Comment: Ayayay! Thank you! Somehow mine got set to "Quick Notes 2" so in addition to the Quick Notes section that I wanted, it kept adding "Quick Notes 2"! This changing this in settings from "Quick Notes 2.one" to just "Quick Notes.one" fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. In the upper left corner, click on File
2. On the left side, click on Options
3. In the OneNote Options window, on the left side, click on Save & Backup
4. At the top of the of the window is a Save section, double-click on the Quick Notes Section option
5. In the Select Location in the OneNote window, select one random name you already have
6. Click on OK
7. Delete the Quick Notes tab if you haven't already

Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! This solved it for me. This does however not remove the functionality and in OneNote 2016 the notebook button «Quick Notes» now takes me to my "default" notebook. But that is ok.

Answer (score 3):

1. Within your `My Notebook`, create a new notebook (I called mine “Dummy Notebook”).

   - Click on the `My Notebook`, then select `Add Notebook`
   - Name your notebook
2. In the upper left corner, click on `FILE`
3. On the left side, click on `Options`
4. In the `OneNote Options` window, on the left side, click on `Save & Backup`
5. At the top of the of the window is a `Save` section, double-click on the `Quick Notes Section` option
6. In the `Select Location in OneNote` window, select the new NoteBook name you created (step 1) and click on `Select`
7. Click on `OK`
8. Exit the `Options` section
9. Exit `OneNote`
10. Delete the `OneNote` file you’ve just created via File Manager:

    - select `My Computer`
    - Delete the directory in `%userprofile%/OneNote Notebooks/newname`

That worked for me.  Good luck.